# Why it's slow to build tree for forward stagewise additive model?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, boosting

According to Elementary Statistical Learning https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf Page 357.
The author pointed there exists no simple method to do tree induction for loss function like Huber loss and deviance loss

My point is, can we use the similar idea as the author mentioned in (10.31)? For any given loss function, we simply use this loss function as the splitting rule to recursively and greedily build the tree. Then it should be as fast as building the tree with the squared-loss error and exponential loss?